# Windows application and message from asynchronous request

Tags: c#, class-library

I have developed a class library (former console application). I want to build a windows forms application arround it to do different kind of actions with the application. For example to pass different values of a startup parameter to the class library.

The class library has a lot of console messages and an error object containing all kind of errors.

On the windows forms application I put 2 textboxes. My goal is to output the console messages to the first textbox (txtMessages) and the errormessages to the second textbox (txtErrorMessages).

The windows application will start the process in the class library as a new thread so it's asynchronous which will cause the windows forms application to instant refresh the textboxes

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. expose 2 events from your library's class:

```
public event Action<string> outputMessage;
public event Action<string> errorMessage;
```

In the library, instead of writing to console you raise those messages. Then in the GUI part you subscribe for that 2 messages, and update your textboxes.

Don't forget you need to marshal the events to your GUI thread to update your controls. I think it'll be easier in the GUI part of the app. To do that, you can use [any method from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/126995) in your event handlers.